# What's the best way to setup one-off pages in EE?

Tags: pages

Each section of this site uses single entries as pages. So in the ABOUT US section, each page under ABOUT US is an entry in the about-us channel. Same for other main sections of the site. The client also needs one-off pages that are not in any of these sections. I've never used the Pages module because I've heard it's crap since I started using EE so I'm not sure if that is an option or not. I've used Structure before, but this site is too far along to install that. What's the best way to set this up so it's easy to do for the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the Pages module extensively for standalone pages. I usually create a "Standalone Web Pages" channel to hold these.

I'd create multiple different channels if I needed significantly different fields on different pages, and/or different categories or statuses. But, otherwise, one channel is fine.

The main human thing with using EE Pages is that you need content editors to enter the Page URI, rather than the URL title. I hide the URL title entry field on channels where I want a Page URI, and move the Page URI field where I'd otherwise put the URL Title.

(Also, you need content editors to choose good Page URIs--if that's a big risk, then this might not work.)

So, what's wrong with EE Pages, imho? Not much, really--but:

- if you list links to pages programmatically (e.g., Search module), you need to switch between {page_uri} and {url_title} depending on which is relevant to the specific entry
- if you ever want to run queries on the Pages in the database, you might need to go through an arcane process of extracting Page URIs via PHP, since they're stored in a seriously fugly manner in the database (they're all serialized into a single row/field in exp_sites!)

Otherwise, I find EE Pages sufficiently convenient for all standalone page content.

Comment: May I suggest something? Check if the segment_1 doesn't match the directory of your standalone pages. I use to put my index and some of the embeds in this directory too, to avoid to create a lot of directories.

Comment: I get the expected segment_1 when using Page URIs. But, I usually have Page URIs be totally distinct from template groups. So, if I have a Page URI as /about/contact, I would try to altogether avoid having a template group named: about. I haven't had actual problems with template group and page uri conflicts (the Page URI beats out the template mapping), but I'd rather avoid even the possibility of this kind of conflict.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about a conflict, but that the templates of this group can still be accessed by "template_group/template_name".